# Issue when upload image to GCP above 2mb - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bucket

I'm trying to upload an image to GCP Bucket, But when I upload a file under 2mb, it work's fine, but when I try to upload a file above 2mb, it throws a message 'failed to upload', I'm using laravel and this is the library, I am using, https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage, I already tried to upload a file of 4mb manually in bucket and it work's fine.

here is my upload code

```
 public function uploadFile(UploadedFile $file, $folder = null, $filename = null)
{
    $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : Str::random(25);

    return $file->storeAs(
        $folder,
        $name . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
        'gcs'
    );
}
```

Comment: what is the message? probably because of your apache/nginx post limit?

Comment: If you are using apache or nginx and you cant upload more than 2 mb, try searching on how to increase the post limit. There should be a lot of articles about that.

Comment: post_max_size 8M 8M

I Already set php.ini

Comment: Did you restart your apache/nginx? After restarting, did you check your `phpinfo()`?

Comment: something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEbKq.png

Comment: I am not sure about GCP Bucket since I have not use it yet. If it has dashboard, did you check if you can view the post_max_size?